# How to get links using curl, but excluding span, style etc

Tags: curl, preg-match, preg-match-all, web-crawler

Here is the code in curl to parse only link of a website (includes all parameteres like span, style):

```
if(preg_match_all('/<a.*?href="(.*?)".*?>(.*?)<\/a>/si',$result,$parts))
{

    $links=$parts[0];

    foreach($links as $link)
    {
        echo $link."<br>";
    }
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

But I want to exclude span, style from the  tag.
how can I edit in that pattern ??

Comment: here is the complete pattern:
'/<a.*?href="(.*?)".*?>(.*?)<\/a>/si'
I can't able to write this in the main question. :(

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to say that if a `<span>` tag appears between `<a>` and `</a>`, you don't want that to appear in the output?

If so, there's no simple way for that to be done in a regular expression, but you could use a function like [strip_tags()](https://www.php.net/strip_tags) on each `$link` before you print it.

By the way, a simpler pattern which may suit your purposes is `/<a .*?<\/a>/`.